# Redirecting stderr when using multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I want to spawn multiple processes using multiprocessing.Pool (python 2.7.13), and redirect stdout / stderr of each process to a file. The problem is it works for stdout, but not for stderr. Here's an example with a single process.

```
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo():

    sys.stdout = open('a.out','w')
    sys.stderr = open('a.err', 'w') 
    print("this must go to a.out.")
    raise Exception('this must go to a.err.')

    return True

def run():

    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    _retvals = []
    _retvals.append( pool.apply_async(foo) )

    retvals = [r.get(timeout=10.) for r in _retvals]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Running `python stderr.py` in terminal (of macbook) produces a.out with correct message ("this must go to a.out"). But it produces empty a.err, and the error message appears in terminal window instead.

If I don't use multiprocessing.Pool and directly run it in the main thread, it produces correct messages on both files. This means replacing run() with the following snippet:

```
def run():
    foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `Pool`s, unhandled exceptions are handled by the the main process.   You should either redirect stderr in `main()`, or wrap your functions like this:

```
def foo():
    sys.stdout = open('x.out', 'a')
    sys.stderr = open('x.err', 'a')
    try:
        print("this goes to x.out.")
        print("this goes to x.err.", file=sys.stderr)
        raise ValueError('this must go to a.err.')
    except:
        traceback.print_exc() 
        raise # optional
```